# need help for write a function that give me all the states of a number

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I have a 192-bit number . and I want two write a function that give me all of the states of this number as follows :
1) all the states with one bit 1
2) all the states with two bits 1
3) all the states with three bits 1
.
.
.
and so on till all of the bits will be 1
also I want to write each of this part in a separate files.

I'v just wrote the states that all of the 1-bits are put together. 
for example:(for 16-bits number)
0000000000000011----> then I shift the bits to the left. But I can't find a good way to give me all of states of two bits.

(I use miracle library in C for this big number)

do you have any idea? 
thank you :)

Comment: You do realise there are about 6 * 10^57 such states, right? That would take a *long* time to print, and consume a *lot* of disk space. (where "a lot" is roughly on the order of observable universe)

Comment: Do you mean *consecutive* bits?

Comment: I'd also like to point out that every single state, printed like that, occupies 192 bytes on the hard drive. The whole process would thus require 192*6*10^57 Bytes on the hard drive. I'm afraid no hard disk currently exists with a capacity of 1152000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 TeraBytes.

Comment: What would you even do with that output? If you read this one number a second you would be reading (boring) numbers for about 10^50 years (certainly more than a lifetime) and you cannot safe it either since there is not nearly enough disk space on earth for this.

Comment: Let's start small. Take a 4-bit number. Show the result you want.

Comment: I should use this number for a test. I have another number for example X that has 192 bit too. I want to inject fault to X by above number in this way.assume this number has named "F". first I should inject fault in 1 bit , so xor X with F that just one bit of it is 1 . and check all the state of one bit. after that in 2 bit and so on. I hope I can explain it in a good way :P

Comment: @Angew : you are right .may be I should limit my test states . thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your functions. but, if you have num and shiftLeft and equals functions, it can be like this

```
for (int i=0;i<192;i+=2)
{
    num->assing(0b11);
    num->shiftLeft(i*2);
    if (num->andOperand(victim)->equals(num))
    {
        //this is the number has two consecutive 11, and only
    }
    if (num->andOperand(victim)->biggerAndEqual(0b11))
    {
        //this is the number has at least one , two consecutive 11
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use 6 for-loops (192/32bit) which loop across all the values of a uint32
inside every-for-loop you can multiply the uint32 by some value to get the right value something like this:

```
for(uint32_t i = 0; i < 0xFFFFFFFF; i++) {
    for(uint32_t j = 0; j < 0xFFFFFFFF; j++) {
        bignumber = j + 0xFFFFFFFF*i
        print(bignumber)
    }
}
```

or if you want to do it really bitwise you could do some bitmasking inside the for-loops

Comment: why not 3 `int64_t`s?

Comment: Even a single 64-bit value would take almost 600 years just to count like that if you can count 1 billion values a second, and maybe several thousand years more to print it out. To loop through all 192-bit values it will take 2^128 times more than that, or nearly 2*10^32 billion years. Do you think it'll finish?

Comment: Well I think it's a strange idea to begin with XD

Answer (score 0):

As the problem was stated there are ((2 ^ 192) - 1) numbers to print, because all permutations are covered except `0` which contains no `1` bits. That is clearly impossible so the question must be asking for consecutive bits set. As @n.m. wrote, get it working with 4 bits first. Then extend it to 192 bits. To shift a number, you double it. This solution works without doing any bit shifting or multiplication - by addition only (apart from the bit mask in `printbits()`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define BITS 4

unsigned printmask;

void printbits (unsigned num) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<BITS; i++) {
        if (num & printmask)
            printf ("1");
        else
            printf ("0");
        num = num + num;
    }
    printf (" ");
}

int main() {
    unsigned num, bits;
    int m, n;
    printmask = 1;                  // prepare bit mask for printing
    for (n=1; n<BITS; n++)
        printmask = printmask + printmask;

    num = 1;
    for (n=0; n<BITS; n++) {
        bits = num;
        for (m=n; m<BITS; m++) {
            printbits (bits);
            bits = bits + bits;
        }
        printf ("\n");
        num = num + num + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
0001 0010 0100 1000
0011 0110 1100
0111 1110
1111
```